# How to build a wheel for nltk which includes wordnet (no download required)?

Tags: nltk, python-wheel

I am building a wheel for a package that uses `word-forms` which in turn uses `nltk`. When this package runs and imports `word-forms` that package then calls `nltk.download("wordnet")` which then croaks since it's running on a machine behind a firewall.

For example:

```
>>> from word_forms.word_forms import get_word_forms
[nltk_data] Error loading wordnet: <urlopen error [WinError 10060] A
[nltk_data]     connection attempt failed because the connected party
[nltk_data]     did not properly respond after a period of time, or
[nltk_data]     established connection failed because connected host
[nltk_data]     has failed to respond>
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.download('popular')
[nltk_data] Error loading popular: <urlopen error [WinError 10060] A
[nltk_data]     connection attempt failed because the connected party
[nltk_data]     did not properly respond after a period of time, or
[nltk_data]     established connection failed because connected host
[nltk_data]     has failed to respond>
False
```

My idea is to build a wheel for `nltk` which already includes the `wordnet` dataset, assuming that this will bypass the `nltk.download()` call. Or maybe instead hack the `word-forms` code to somehow accomplish the same thing? I will build the wheel file on a machine that does have access to the internet and then copy it into the firewalled machine via SFTP.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this by downloading the NLTK data on a separate machine then uploading it to the firewalled server via SFTP.

The download was performed using the command `python -m nltk.downloader all`.

Then in my Python code on the firewalled machine, I have added this:

```
os.environ['NLTK_DATA'] = 'H:/path/to/nltk_data'
```

Everything seems to work as advertised now.

(Thanks to the `word_forms` project for the helpful guidance on [this issue](https://github.com/gutfeeling/word_forms/issues/24).)